# Вывести все значения через запятую из таблицы в MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть такая таблица:

```
user   || user_id || site || date || date_support || modul ||

test   |    1    | site.ru  | 14.09 |   13.09      |  cms
test   |    1    | site.net | 15.09 |   12.09      |  cms
test1  |    11   | site.org | 16.09 |   14.09      |  cms
test   |    1    | site.com | 17.09 |   15.09      |  cms
test1  |    11   | site.guru| 18.09 |   16.09      |  cms
test2  |    12   | site.ua  | 19.09 |   18.09      |  cms
test   |    1    | site.fr  | 14.09 |   19.09      |  cms
```

Есть такой запрос у меня:

```
"SELECT user, user_id, site, MIN(date) AS flag, MAX(date_support) AS flag1  FROM license where modul = 'cms'  GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 order by flag"
```

Запрос находит в таблице modul повторяющиеся значения и сортирует по флагу.

Как сделать, чтобы мне вывело все сайты из таблицы site через запятую? Так как сейчас выводит только один!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените site на group_concat(site)

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Дополню уже данный ответ. У функции `GROUP_CONCAT()` есть полезные опции для исключения дубликатов и сортировки листа элементов, которые очень часто используются.

То есть, запрос будет такой:

```sql
SELECT 
    user, user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT site ORDER BY date DESC), 
    MIN(date) AS flag, MAX(date_support) AS flag1  
FROM license 
where modul = 'cms'  
GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
order by flag
```